# How to obtain small bins after FFT in python?

Tags: python, signal-processing, fft

I'm using `scipy.signal.fft.rfft()` to calculate power spectral density of a signal. The sampling rate is 1000Hz and the signal contains 2000 points. So frequency bin is `(1000/2)/(2000/2)=0.5Hz`. But I need to analyze the signal in **[0-0.1]Hz**.

I saw several answers recommending chirp-Z transform, but I didn't find any toolbox of it written in Python.

So how can I complete this small-bin analysis in Python? Or can I just filter this signal to [0-0.1]Hz using like **Butterworth filter**?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even if you use another transform, that will not make more data.

If you have a sampling of 1kHz and 2s of samples, then your precision is 0.5Hz. You can interpolate this with chirpz (or just use sinc(), that's the shape of your data between the samples of your comb), but the data you have on your current point is the data that determines what you have in the lobes (between 0Hz and 0.5Hz).

If you want a real precision of 0.1Hz, you need 10s of data.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I cannot come up with how to use sinc() here. Could you please give more details?@Matthieu Brucher

Comment: I've updated my questions, can I use filters to filter the signal to 0-0.1Hz, and then apply FFT on it? Thank you~ @Matthieu Brucher

Comment: You mean like a low pass with 0.1Hz? that will not change the result, especially since the filter will also modify heavily this band if you use a cut frequency at 0.1Hz.

Answer (score 1):

You can't get smaller frequency bins to separate out close spectral peaks unless you use more (a longer amount of) data.

You can't just use a narrower filter because the transient response of such a filter will be longer than your data.

You can get smaller frequency bins that are just a smooth interpolation between nearby frequency bins, for instance to plot the spectrum on wider paper or at a higher dpi graphic resolution, by zero-padding the data and using a longer FFT.  But that won't create more detail.

Comment: OK.Thanks for your answer.